# JSON datetime "array to string conversion" error

Tags: php, json, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I'm trying to send a datetime field in JSON.

Here my JSON:

```
"mydate": "2015-07-07T22:00:00.000Z"
```

Here the PHP/Doctrine declaration:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(name="mydate", type="datetime")
 */
private $mydate;
```

But when I send the JSON in POST method, I got that error:

```
{
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Notice: Array to string conversion"
}
```

After debugging, I found that the error occur when my REST API Bundle (LemonRestBundle) calls the dezerialize() JMS method.

I just don't know why JMS can't deserialize my date to a PHP \DateTime... (if this is the problem...)

I've also tried this format:

```
"mydate": {
  "lastErrors": {
      "warning_count":0,
      "warnings":[],
      "error_count":0,
      "errors":[]
  },
  "timezone": {
      "name":"Europe\/Warsaw",
      "location": {
          "country_code":"PL",
          "latitude":52.25,
          "longitude":21,
          "comments":""
      }
   },
   "offset":7200,
   "timestamp":1399413600
}
```

And thing like that:

```
"mydate": "2015/07/12"
```

Can someone help me on this ? Thanks! ;)

Comment: How do you know it complains on date? Pasting your serialised config could help too.

Comment: Because I've others fields, and without "mydate" I've just an SQL Server error "Cannot insert the value NULL into column '%.*ls', table '%.*ls'; column does not allow nulls. %ls fails." That mean that the serialization works, but failed with the date.